# Releasing camera object in surfaceChanged causes force close (Null Pointer Exception)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, surfaceview, preview

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

..........
.......

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    ........
    ..........
    // I create camera object with camera.open
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // I start camera preview successfully and call my function.
   Myfunction();
   //this function does some checking (a separate thread ) n releases camera object immediately and also release the camera preview
  }
}
```

Now that I am still in `onsurfaceChanged()` when the control leaves this function I get a Force close(`Null Pointer exception`) at `SurfaceView (564)`. I know this error is because i released the camera and its suface view. According to the documentation of android the `onsurfaceChanged()` is called atleast once after `surfaceCreated();`

So my Query is it wrong that i am releasing the camera object and its preview holder before the control goes out of `onsurfaceChanged()`?? My requirement is I check some situation n release the camera if its condition is false as soon as create preview i.e `startPreview();` do some task ahead inside `onsurfaceChanged()` itself.

is there any way i can detect the `onsurfaceChanged()` is called once and then i can trigger  `Myfunction();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy workaround would be to use `CameraPreview.post()` to release camera *after* your callback returns:

```
public class CameraPreview … {

    void Myfunction() {
        …
        this.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: @yeahman: **View.post()** delays execution of the block, and makes sure that the camera is not released while framework still believes that the camera is active. It is easy in this case, because `onsurfaceChanged()` callback also runs on the UI thread. If you want to do something like this in a camera callback, make sure you use the same looper as the camera callbacks.